# Is the function globally Lipschitz?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis, analysis

Let $f : \mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous and vanishing at infinity. It is then known that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}^d$. Now, if $f$ is Lipschitz on compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}^d$, does it follow that it is also globally Lipschitz?

Here is what I have come up with. Let $\varepsilon > 0$ be arbitrary. Then there exists $M > 0$ such that $|f(x)|< \varepsilon$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$ with $|x|>M$. Since $f$ is Lipschitz on compact sets, there exists $L :=L(M) >0$ such that
$$
|f(x)-f(y)| \leq L|x-y| \quad \forall x,y \in \overline{B(0, M)},
$$
where $\overline{B(0, M)}$ is the closed ball with radius $M$ and center $0$. Is it possible to combine the two observations to obtain a global Lipschitz constant? It seems that one should consider two cases: $|x| \leq M$, $|y| > M$ and $|x|>M$, $|y|>M$.

Answer (score 3):

Another counterexample: Define $f\colon \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ by placing at every $n\in \mathbb N$ a little hat of width $1/n^2$ and height $1/n$ and setting the function equal to zero otherwise. This way the slopes are unbounded - preventing the function from being globally Lipschitz - while you only see finitely many hats on every compact set, making the function locally Lipschitz.

Answer (score 1):

No, for example $f(x)=\sin(e^x)/(1+x^2)$. If we suppose there exists such an $L$, then using the mean value theorem and the points $x_n=\ln(2n+1/2)$, we find a contradiction.